# Can we see a text files property in Gdrive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I saved a text file using gdrive api and also saved property with file using a key. I am able to get the property of file using gdrive api method in console. but can any one tell me that we can see file properties in gdrive itself in browser.
I used service.properties().insert(fileId, newProperty).execute(); this api to set the property.
Visibility is private
Thankyou